# how to add multiple document to firestore after launching the app to the app store?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on my very first flutter app, and I was wondering what are the possible ways to add multiple documents to the cloud firestore after launching the app to the app store? I know that I can do it manually on the firestore but the question is, can I do it using the source code of my app? or is there another way? Currently, I used this way to add products:

```
 Future<void> addBsBooks() async {
    try {
      _products.forEach(
        (book) {
          productsCollection.add(
            {
              'id': product.id,
              'title': product.title,
              'price': product.price,
              'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
              'category': product.category,
              'storeId': product.storeId,
              'isFavorite': product.isFavorite,
            },
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: You want add some default data?

Comment: let's say that i have an online market, and i want to add some more products

Answer (score 1):

heres a simple example:

```
final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;

firestoreInstance.collection("products").document(productId).setData({
  'title': product.title,
  'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
  'category': product.category,
  'storeId': product.storeId,
  'isFavorite': product.isFavorite,
}, merge: true);
```

example to retrieve from database.

```
var result =
    await firestoreInstance.collection("products").document(productId).get();

String title = result['title'];
```

Comment: can i use this after publishing the app to the app store?